# Tabbar autolayout issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitabbar

I got a strange glitch on iPhone 6 device (only on device. Simulators works fine. And i assume another real devices will have the same problem). Here is the video: https://youtu.be/_s3C1RnPG_I

Also, on iPhone X simulator there is a blank empty space under message sending view,

[image]

but i want something like this.

[image]

Here is a constraints for message sending view:

[image]

Definitely something wrong with bottom constraint but i tried almost all and nothing has helped.

Comment: Are you adding custom tabbar or custom UIView?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple -
Interface Builder uses UIView.safeAreaLayoutGuide as a replacement for the deprecated Top and Bottom layout guides in `UIViewController`. To use the new safe area, select Safe Area Layout Guides in the File inspector for the view controller, and then add constraints between your content and the new safe area anchors. This prevents your content from being obscured by top and bottom bars, and by the overscan region on `tvOS`. Constraints to the safe area are converted to Top and Bottom when deploying to earlier versions of iOS.

[image]

Here is simple reference as a comparison (to make similar visual effect) between existing (Top & Bottom) Layout Guide and Safe Area Layout Guide.

**Safe Area Layout:** 
[image]

**AutoLayout:**

[image]

Comment: Wow! Great answer! But, unfortunately, Safe area already activated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9) article for calculating size of bars.

First assign Leading, Trailing, Bottom and Height constraints for custom message view according below:

[image]

Then edit bottom constraints as below:
Change second item to view.Top & Constant = 44 (height of message view)

[image]